# nix package manager: perl warning: Setting locale failed

Tags: opensuse, perl, locale, nixos, nix

Whenever I run a command for the nix package manager (e.g. nix-channel --update) I get the following warning:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I suspect it's somehow related to nix since other perl scripts don't show this behaviour (I tried `perl -e exit` and something using WWW::Curl).

Changing the locale settings does reflect in the output of the warning, but the warning is still shown with every configuration I could think of.

OS is openSUSE.

What can I do?

Comment: What about `perl -w -e exit`?

Comment: No warning either

Comment: Just remembered where I've seen this before.  Have a look at my answer **[to this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12663/couldnt-start-vnc-in-raspbian)** and see if it works for you.

Comment: Hm, these files don't exist on my system. Also, openSUSE doesn't have locale-gen.
I never had to deal with locales, so I'll go to the openSUSE forums and ask what's the intended way to configure this on this system.

I find it still strange that I only get this error when running nix commands and not when directly running perl commands.

Comment: Have you had a look [at this](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_114/opensuse-reference/cha.y2.lang.html)?  `locale-gen` turns out to just be a shell script that wraps `localedef`, which probably *is* on your system (it's on fedora, which also doesn't use `locale-gen`, and it's [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/localedef.html)).  I'd rather visit the dentist though ;) The locale-gen script is pretty short but you'll have to pull it off a debian derived system or download a .deb to look at it.

Comment: Interesting. But yeah, that does look pretty painful.
Meanwhile I found that exporting LC_ALL=C actually helps. Would that have any negative side effects?

Comment: Some TLI apps *may* not handle UTF-8 well that way, but otherwise I believe it's fine.

Comment: Ok, then I will post this workaround as the answer for now. Since I have only one language installed, which doesn't make any trouble except with nix, I guess nix makes some assumptions about locales which don't apply on openSUSE...
Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `export LC_ALL=C` I actually got rid of the warning.

This is more of a workaround (as LC_ALL is also strongly discouraged), but my guess is the reason for this behaviour lies in assumptions nix makes about locales on the system which don't apply on openSUSE.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently this is a problem in nix. There is an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/599) with a proposed [workaround](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/599#issuecomment-153885553) by setting the `LOCALE_ARCHIVE` variable.

If you already have nix installed just do:

1. `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.glibcLocales`
2. And in your bash profile:

   `export LOCALE_ARCHIVE="$(nix-env --installed --no-name --out-path --query glibc-locales)/lib/locale/locale-archive"`

   (all as one line).

Comment: I think this may be `nixpkgs.glibcLocales`, not `nixpkgs.glibc-locales`.

Answer (score 1):

Found this during a search and thought I'd give the solution.

You just need to provide the variable `LOCALE_ARCHIVE` in the environment pointing to a `locale-archive`.

## Option 1

Use a previously installed system `locale-archive`.

Make sure it's actually there

```
# should find the file
ls /lib/locale/locale-archive
```

Add this to your `/etc/.profile` and/or `~/.bashrc/` and/or `~/.zshrc` to have it always set in your shell:

```
export LOCALE_ARCHIVE="/lib/locale/locale-archive"
```

## Option 2a : Without flake + sub-command support

(source: cyraxjoe above https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243189/119561)

Install locale support from nix.

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.glibcLocales
```

Make sure you can find it:

```
# should give you a path to a folder in your /nix/store
nix-env --installed --no-name --out-path --query glibc-locales

# should find the file
ls $(nix-env --installed --no-name --out-path --query glibc-locales)/lib/locale/locale-archive
```

Add this to your `/etc/.profile` and/or `~/.bashrc/` and/or `~/.zshrc` to have it always set in your shell:

```
export LOCALE_ARCHIVE="$(nix-env --installed --no-name --out-path --query glibc-locales)/lib/locale/locale-archive"
```

## Option 2b : With flake + sub-command support

Install locale support from nix.

```
nix profile install nixpkgs#glibcLocales
```

Make sure you can find it:

```
# should give you a path to a folder in your /nix/store
nix profile list | grep glibcLocales | tail -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f4

# should find the file
ls $(nix profile list | grep glibcLocales | tail -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f4)/lib/locale/locale-archive
```

Add this to your `/etc/.profile` and/or `~/.bashrc/` and/or `~/.zshrc` to have it always set in your shell:

```
export LOCALE_ARCHIVE="$(nix profile list | grep glibcLocales | tail -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f4)/lib/locale/locale-archive"
```